# business logic in Django

Tags: python, django

I'd like to know where to put code that doesn't belong to a view, I mean, the logic.

I've been reading a few similar posts, but couldn't arrive to a conclusion.

What I could understand is:

- A View is like a controller, and lot of logic should not put in the controller.
- Models should not have a lot of logic either.

So where is all the logic based stuff supposed to be?

I'm coming from Groovy/Grails and for example if we need to access the DB or if we have a complex logic, we use services, and then those services are injected into the controllers.

Is it a good practice to have .py files containing things other than Views and Models in Django?

PS: I've read that some people use a `services.py`, but then other people say this is a bad practice, so I'm a little confused...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Django is more of a MTV or MVT (Model / Template / View), as described in the official FAQ : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names

The business logic has its place in your views, but nothing prevents you from putting it inside a "utils.py", "services.py" or anything to your liking.

Comment: that is what I've seen in a bunch of Django packages, a file called utils.py, I will start using this, thanks!

Comment: utils.py usually sounds like a lack of design. It doesn't go anywhere else so put it here. Business logic certainly doesn't sound like it belongs in a utils.py

Comment: No, it doesn't. Don't just dump everything into `utils.py` - it will turn into a nightmare!

Answer (score 8):

I don't know why you say

> we can't put a lot of logic in the controller, and we cannot have the models with a lot of logic either

You can certainly put logic in either of those places. It depends to a great extent what that logic is: if it's specifically related to a single model class, it should go in the model. If however it's more related to a specific page, it can go in a view.

Alternatively, if it's more general logic that's used in multiple views, you could put it in a separate utility module. Or, you could use class-based views with a superclass that defines the logic, and subclasses which inherit from it.

Answer (score 8):

Having a java background I can relate with this question.
I have been working on python for quite some time.  Even though I do my best to treat Java as Java and Python as Python, some times I mix them both so that I can get a good deal out of both.

In short

1. Put all model related stuff in models app,  it could be from simply models definition to custom save , pre save hooks .....
2. Put any request/ response related stuff in views,  and some logic like verifying Jon schema, validation request body ... handling exceptions and so on ....
3. Put your business logic in separate folder/ app  or module per views directory/ app. Meaning have separate middle module between your models and views.

There isn't strict rule to organise your code as long as you are consistent.

**Project : Ci**

- Models: ci/model/device.py
- Views: ci/views/list_device.py
- Business logic:

  - (1) ci/business_logic/discover_device.py

    Or
  - (2) ci/views/discover_device.py

Answer (score 1):

If the functionality fits well as a method of some model instance, put it there. After all, models are just classes.

Otherwise, just write a Python module (some .py file) and put the code there, just like in any other Python library.

Don't put it in the views. Views should be the only part of your code that is aware of HTTP, and they should stay as small as possible.