# Most of my calculations in the views.py, how to clean or do correctly?

Tags: python, django

I have some calculations that help me find total amounts for teachers earnings, made from the number of lessons they have, their rate, their costs, etc.

Where is this meant to go as I'm sure it's not in the correct place and could be a lot more efficient?

I thought about making some of the work in the models.py as an @property but not sure how to or even if it is that necessary.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
 def accounts(request):
    lessons=Lessons.objects.all()

    basic_band= lessons.filter(price_band="BASIC")
    top_band=lessons.filter(price_band="TOP")
    native_band=lessons.filter(price_band="NATIVE")

    basic_count=basic_band.count()
    top_count=top_band.count()
    native_count=native_band.count()

    native_house_rate   =0.25
    top_house_rate    =0.30

    basic_rate=300
    top_rate=400
    native_rate=700


    ##earnings
    basic_earning= basic_count * basic_rate
    top_earning= top_count * top_rate
    native_earning= native_count * native_rate
    ##fees
    native_house_fee=native_earning * native_house_rate
    top_house_fee=top_earning * top_house_rate
    ##totals    
    total_top = top_earning - top_house_fee
    total_native = native_earning - native_house_fee

    total_earning= total_top + total_native
    total_gross_earning=top_earning + native_earning

    monthly_top= total_top * 4
    monthly_native= total_native * 4

    monthly_total= monthly_top + monthly_native

    context{"total_gross":total_gross_earning,"native_number":native_earning,
    "top_number":top_earning,"basic_number":basic_earning, "basic":basic_count, 
    "top":top_count,"native":native_count, "native_fee":native_house_fee, 
    "top_fee":top_house_fee, "top_rate":top_rate, "native_rate":native_rate,
    "basic_rate":basic_rate,"total":total_earning,
    "native_house_rate":native_house_rate,"top_house_rate":top_house_rate,
    "total_top":total_top, "total_native":total_native, "monthly_top":monthly_top, 
    "monthly_native":monthly_native,"monthly_total":monthly_total}
    return render(request, "accounts.html", context)
```

models.py:

```
class Lessons(models.Model):
    student             = models.ForeignKey(Students, 
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)  
    headed_by           = models.ForeignKey(Tutors, 
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    day                 = models.CharField(max_length=4, 
    choices=DAY_CHOICES, null=True)
    start_time          = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    type                = models.CharField(max_length=7, 
    choices=TYPE_CHOICES, null=True)
    price_band          = models.CharField(max_length=7, 
    choices=PAYMENT_TYPE_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    created             = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True )
   
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.student) + " / " + str(self.day)
    class Meta:
        ordering=['student',"headed_by",'day','start_time']
```

Comment: can you share `Lessons` model ?

Comment: i have edited my first comment to show the Lessons model also.

Comment: why every Lesson object has only one student? is it intended or misconception?

Comment: It’s private tuition, and for the majority of cases it’s only one child per session

Comment: I think basically your question is: where do I put my business logic? If that's the case, then basically any module _except_ models or views. Both for separation of concerns, and for making it much easier to test that logic. Also see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21378821/1284043

Comment: @MarkM thank you very much for your reply, i will be doing something very similar with my ongoing projects and projects in the future, either a utils, or services etc, for the reasons that you've stated.